# How does compareValues function get compare between two Strings if the signature says: fun <T : Comparable<*>>

Tags: android, kotlin, generics, any

I'm looking at the following method in Kotlin:

```
public fun <T : Comparable<*>> compareValues(a: T?, b: T?): Int {
    if (a === b) return 0
    if (a == null) return -1
    if (b == null) return 1

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return (a as Comparable<Any>).compareTo(b)
}
```

I can't understand two things:

1. How does this code can gets two *String*'s and compare between them if String can be compared only with String and not with All object (meaning of asterisk). Here is *String* class signature:

> public class String : Comparable<**String**>, CharSequence

2. Why in the last line it is written **Any** and not only * or instead not writing the triangle brackets at all?

Comment: For the second, on invariant types `Nothing` is the captured type when we provide star-projection and without triangle brackets it is impossible to compile as compiler can't infer the type from star-projection at compile time.

Comment: For the third maybe i will understand (i really hope so). Sorry that it so hard for me to understand. really sorry. Although you say that star projection has a meaning of *Nothing* it still doesn't help me to understand how a String that according to definition can compare only to itself, can be compared with *Nothing*. And if it is *Nothing* so why does in the triangle it is written Any and not  Nothing?

Comment: `Nothing` is imaginary subtype of all the types in the type system. There is no instance that can satisfy that, that's why you can't use star-projections there. In invariance, the captured type of T at return site is `Any?` the super of all, and at inputs its `Nothing` subtype of all the type.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, sorry i will read again all Kotlin generics and try to understand. It is very desperate me. Thanks

Comment: Ya, I'd suggest checking out this article: [Understanding Generics in Kotlin](https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-generics-and-variance-in-kotlin-714c14564c47) And by the way the reason they did not casted to T is probably cuz the generics are erased so there's no benefit to do so, casting to Any and T would have the same effect at runtime.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu, i have difficult with star projection, i thought that is like a *?* in java generics buy you told me that is *Nothing*. The link you send me doesn't talks about the things that are hard for me (especially projection)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225271/discussion-between-animesh-sahu-and-eitanos30).